# Jenkins log each page load

Tags: logging, jenkins

I have an issue in Jenkins: page load time takes much longer than it should. There are multiple Jenkins instances in the host that acts as a server for my Jenkins and none of them seem to lag that much. I need to investigate this.

How can I configure Jenkins to log each page load process step by step what happens after what with timestamps?

I'd assume that using `Manage Jenkins -> system log -> New logger` should work, but what should be selected as `logger` there?

Answer (score 1):

Check [Logging](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging)

Also,below will give you complete log

```
http://your_server/log/all
```

If you need to filter content according to logger which is the name of the class class or plugin which you want to take log of.

For eg:-

If I want to get log of all those who login to my server ,given I use Active directory plugin,I would use

```
"hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm"
```

Similarly just check in the config.xml file, which thing you want to log and specify that respective class

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this does help but I'm already using this as stated in the question. What I want is much *much* more detailed log and it may simply be in a different place or not even exist. Jenkins system log -> all gives very small amount of data.

Comment: add this to logger "ava.util.logger.Logger" and "jenkins.util.ErrorLoggingScheduledThreadPoolExecutor" 
and Log level "All".
I think it should help